# How we can decode an Instruction from a list in a transaction receipt

Tags: transactions, metaplex, instructions, web3.js, solscan

I would like to decode a sell instruction from a transaction, to obtain instruction detail.  Idem as make Solscan with a transaction after we sell an NFT on Opensea or Magiceden. For example the code to get an instruction from a transaction is:

```
const result = await connection.getParsedTransaction(signature)
result.transaction.message.instructions[NUMBER].parsed
```

but sometimes I got an "undefined" response, and sometimes I got the response. For example I got the response from Transfer Instruction. But not all instruction can be decoded. So I want to know a correct way to do this.
Here is an example of transaction with 6 instruction and the first one is the Sell instruction and I can't get a correct response from the code above.
https://solscan.io/tx/3mdZshAycXoGKRHENrWpVYfAhtjEMQqXcLRXcbE1Y3E9hstNTWie9i1MCYneTbrtddK7xg2P8aEHFoS8hAeXu1WL

Answer (score 2):

Solana enforces no serialization or data structure on account/instruction data, so programs are free to implement both however they wish.  This makes it impossible to generically parse the data fields

As such, the parsing is done by the RPC node, which only knows about programs/instructions for which parsers have been explicitly added.  Most likely the program/instruction you wish to inspect does not have a parser added.  You can likely parse the data field yourself, but will likely need documentation or a helper library provided by the given protocol.  Not all protocols provide such information though, so you would need to reverse engineer the data format in that case

Answer (score 0):

- Regarding the `undefined` resonse that you sometimes get, this is likely caused by the `commitment` you are requesting the transaction with. Change it to a lower commitment, so you can get the data quicker and more consistently, would be an idea.
- To get the data, you may need to deserialize the instruction data of the inner instructions using a library or by hand.